# AJAX not submitting the form after validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, form-submit

The below is my js validation code along with form submit event.

The issue is that when I submit the form it validates for user id and name and does not proceed ahead. But if I remove the login id validation then it just checks for user name and submits the form properly.

Firebug shows that its validating login id and getting stopped doing nothing ahead. I get "0" in response from database if login id is available.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var value = $('#button input').val();
    var name = $('#button input').attr('name');

    $('#button input').remove();
    $('#button').html('<a href="#" class="cssSubmitButton" rel=' + name + '>' + value + '</a>');

    //global vars
    var form = $("#customForm");
    var name = $("#name");
    var nameInfo = $("#nameInfo");
    var login_id = $("#login_id");
    var login_idInfo = $("#login_idInfo");

    //On blur
    name.blur(validateName);
    login_id.blur(validatelogin_id);

    //On key press
    name.keyup(validateName);
    login_id.keyup(validatelogin_id);

    //On Submitting
    $('#button a').on('click', function () {

        var link = $(this);
        if (validateName() & validatelogin_id()) //it validates login id here and gets stuck; if i remove validatelogin_id() it processes the form perfectly
        {
            var str = $("form").serializeArray();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'load.php',
                data: str,
                type: 'POST',
                cache: 'false',
                beforeSend: function () {
                    link.addClass('loading');
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    link.removeClass('loading');
                    $('#button').css('display', 'none');
                    $('#success').css('display', 'block');

                },
                error: function (x, e) {

                }
            });

            return true
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });

    //validation functions
    function validatelogin_id() {
        //if it's NOT valid
        if (login_id.val().length < 4) {
            $('#login_id_correct').css('display', 'none');
            login_id.addClass("error");
            login_idInfo.text("We want names with more than 3 letters!");
            login_idInfo.addClass("error");
            return false;
        }
        //if it's valid
        else {

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "./include/check_user_name.php",
                data: "username=" + login_id.val(),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == 0) {
                        $('#login_id_correct').css('display', 'block');
                        login_id.removeClass("error");
                        login_idInfo.text("What's your name?");
                        login_idInfo.removeClass("error");
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        $('#login_id_correct').css('display', 'none');
                        login_id.addClass("error");
                        login_idInfo.text("Username already used!");
                        login_idInfo.addClass("error");
                        return false;

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    function validateName() {
        //if it's NOT valid
        if (name.val().length < 4) {
            name.addClass("error");
            nameInfo.text("We want names with more than 3 letters!");
            nameInfo.addClass("error");
            return false;
        }
        //if it's valid
        else {
            name.removeClass("error");
            nameInfo.text("What's your name?");
            nameInfo.removeClass("error");
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You are using ajax to validate login_id but the function execution will not wait for the ajax call to return, it will make the ajax call and then return nothing from the `else` clause

Comment: What does `validatelogin_id` return? Because the AJAX request in that function is asynchronous and is a function itself, so could possible be that your function never returns `true` .

Comment: @anu so what can be the possible solution in this case. I am desperate to check login id along other values during form submit.

Comment: you are already validating the login_id onkeyup and onblur events, so what you can do is declare a global variable and set its value to true or false in the `validatelogin_id()` function and then while submitting check this variable's value and not call the `validatelogin_id()` again that time

Comment: @putvande I get "0" in firebug so I assume it is returning true.

Comment: That would be more like a `false`, `true` would be 1.

Comment: That `0` I assume is the result of the ajax call not the result of `validatelogin_id()`. Have you tried my solution?

Comment: @anu I get 0 as a reply on ajax success. So `if (data == 0) {` part of code gets executed.

Comment: Yes thats what I said. Have you tried my suggestion of using a gloabal flag?

Comment: ok got it let me try.

Comment: Set its default value to false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is  valid assuming you are calling `validatelogin_id()` on onblur event

```
valid_id = false; //declare a global flag

function validatelogin_id() {
        if (login_id.val().length < 4) {
            $('#login_id_correct').css('display', 'none');
            login_id.addClass("error");
            login_idInfo.text("We want names with more than 3 letters!");
            login_idInfo.addClass("error");
            valid_id = false; //set value of global flag           
        }
        else {

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "./include/check_user_name.php",
                data: "username=" + login_id.val(),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == 0) {
                        $('#login_id_correct').css('display', 'block');
                        login_id.removeClass("error");
                        login_idInfo.text("What's your name?");
                        login_idInfo.removeClass("error");
                        valid_id = true; //set value of global flag
                    } else {
                        $('#login_id_correct').css('display', 'none');
                        login_id.addClass("error");
                        login_idInfo.text("Username already used!");
                        login_idInfo.addClass("error");
                        valid_id = false; //set value of global flag
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Then change this line

```
if (validateName() & validatelogin_id())
```

to

```
if (validateName() & valid_id)
```

Comment: one question over here is when I click form submit and if I don't enter any thing in login_id. It does not submit form but also It does not show that login id is not entered or is invalid....in short how should i call validatelogin_id() function so that error message is highlighted.

Comment: For that specific purpose you can call `validatelogin_id()` as the first line before validation or trigger a blur event on that input element